# What is the purpose of the Etag field in G Suite APIs?

Tags: google-api, google-workspace, etag

I have seen that every query response contains at least one etag value.

What is the exact purpose of providing it?

For instance:

```
{
  "kind": "admin#directory#user#photo",
  "id": string,
  "etag": etag,
  "primaryEmail": string,
  "mimeType": string,
  "height": integer,
  "width": integer,
  "photoData": bytes
}
```

Comment: Did you read the tag you've used: [tag:etag]?

Comment: Thank you, @jonrsharpe. I am aware of the [RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7232#section-2.3). What I was looking for is the G Suite official documentation about its usage with the API. Some examples [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/version-resources)

Answer (score 2):

The ETag is a data hash that can be used to indicate a particular version. It updates when the data changes.

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hashes-etags#_ETags